# Updating dictionary in a marshalled object

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a problem updating dictionary that is a property of a MarshallByRef object. My marshalled object is a configuration object that has some basic datatypes and aforementioned dictionary. It is created on one AppDomain and passed to the other Appdomain as an interface.

```
public clas FFIConfiguration : MarshalByRefObject, IUserConfig
{
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public DateTime ExecutionTime {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<String, String> ParametersDict { get; set; }
}
```

This object is passed to another Appdomain where it is used as an interface like this:

```
IUserConfig config = parameterPassedAsMarshalled;
config.ExecutionTime = DateTime.Now;
config.ParametersDict.Add("Key",Value");
config.ParametersDict["Key"] = "Some other value";
```

When i try to set any of the int, string or datetime properties it works as charm. But when i add anything to the Dictionary it remains unchanged.

I can serialize the dictionary and store it as string then deserialize it later, but i would really like to avoid this. Is there any other solution to the problem?

Comment: Add methods to the interface to do required operations.

Comment: Thank you leppie that did the trick. I totally forgot that this job could be executed on the source domain as well.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer for some rep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from leppie I've made it work.

The original class now has a method that sets the dictionary:

```
public clas FFIConfiguration : MarshalByRefObject, IUserConfig
{
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public DateTime ExecutionTime {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<String, String> ParametersDict { get; set; }
    public void SetToDictionary(string key, string value)
    {
        if (ParametersDict.ContainsKey(key))
            ParametersDict[key] = value;
        else
            ParametersDict.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

This way dictionary is set on the original AppDomain and it works as intended.